# Given an array of integers, return the smallest positive integer not in it

Tags: javascript, sorting

> Write a function:
>
> ```
> function solution(A);
> ```
>
> that, given an array `A` of `N` integers, returns the smallest positive
>   integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in `A`.
>
> For example, given `A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2]`, the function should return
>   5.
>
> Given `A = [1, 2, 3]`, the function should return 4.
>
> Given `A = [−1, −3]`, the function should return 1.
>
> Assume that:
>
> - `N` is an integer within the range [1..100,000]
> - Each element of array `A` is an integer within the range [−1,000,000..1,000,000]
>
> Complexity:
>
> - Expected worst-case time complexity is \$O(N)\$
> - Expected worst-case space complexity is \$O(N)\$, beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments)
>
> Elements of input arrays can be modified.

**Solution in \$O(n^2)\$:**

```
function solution(A) {
  for (i = 1; i < 1000000; i++) {
    if(!A.includes(i)) return i;
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not know the guidelines of this site, but to me this is not a code review question, as you seem to expect to be given an algorithm that you have not found yourself.

Comment: @CarstenS It is a valid code review post, working code, clear explanation, asking for advice.

Comment: Easy Way
-----------------

function solution(Arr) {
    // write your code in JavaScript (Node.js 8.9.4)
    const min = Math.min(...Arr);
    const max = Math.max(...Arr);
    if (min < 0 && !Arr.includes(1)) {
      return 1;
    }
    let smallestPIntNot = [];
    for (let i=1; i<=max+1; i++) {
        if (!Arr.includes(i)) {
            smallestPIntNot.push(i);
        }
    }
    return smallestPIntNot[0];
}

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53466817/fastest-way-to-find-smallest-missing-integer-from-list-of-integers/59283216#59283216

Comment: const next = (p, c) => {
    p.seen.add(c);
    while (p.seen.has(p.res)) ++p.res;
    return p
}
const solution = A => A.reduce(next, {res: 1, seen: new Set}).res

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That's a nice simple solution, with two problems:

1. It will give incorrect result when `A` contains all the values in the ranges `[1..1000000]` or `[1..999999]`, returning `undefined` instead of 1000001 and 1000000, respectively.
2. It doesn't meet the time complexity requirement, being \$O(n^2)\$ instead of \$O(n)\$.

The first problem is easy to fix by adjusting the end condition of the loop.

The second problem is trickier, and the interesting part of the exercise.
Consider this algorithm, that's \$O(n)\$ in time and \$O(1)\$ in space:

- Loop over the elements of `A` from the start, and for each value `A[i]`, if `A[i] - 1` is a valid index in the array, then repeatedly swap `A[i]` and `A[A[i] - 1]` until `A[i]` is in its correct place (value equal to `i + 1`), or `A[i]` and `A[A[i] - 1]` are equal.

  - This should order the values to their right places such that `A[i] == i + 1`, when possible
- Loop over the elements again to find an index where `A[i] != i + 1`, if exists then the missing value is `i + 1`
- If the end of the loop is reached without returning a value, then the missing value is `A.length + 1`.

Here's one way to implement this in JavaScript:

```
var firstMissingPositive = function(nums) {
    var swap = function(i, j) {
        var tmp = nums[i];
        nums[i] = nums[j];
        nums[j] = tmp;
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        while (0 < nums[i] && nums[i] - 1 < nums.length
                && nums[i] != i + 1
                && nums[i] != nums[nums[i] - 1]) {
            swap(i, nums[i] - 1);
        }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] != i + 1) {
            return i + 1;
        }
    }
    return nums.length + 1;
};
```

Note: to verify this, or alternative implementations work,
you could submit on [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/first-missing-positive/description/).

Comment: What is the time complexity of this? It isn't even that easy to confirm that it terminates, not to mention is `O(n)`

Comment: The exchange loop runs in O (n): That's because every exchange operation puts one value x into its right place that wasn't in the right place before, and because at most N values can be in the wrong place there can be at most N exchange operations.

Comment: @gnasher729 why do you only count the number exchanges, but not the exchanges themselves towards complexity? I believe, the algorithm above is a kind of comparison-based sorting, in a way similar to insertion sort... so, we aren't even talking about `O(log n)` here...

Comment: swapping makes this algorithm complex. You can write the number in the correct position of a fresh array (or discard them when they are to large) a second iteration over that array finds the correct number.

Comment: @JensSchauder You could, but you would have `O(n)` additional space complexity, while this algorithm only uses `O(1)`; just to get rid of some perceived complicatedness.

Comment: @wvxvw It's actually a lot like bucketsort, but even faster because collisions are simply skipped, making the worst case `O(n)`.

Comment: @Sanchises bucket sort isn't really `O(n)`... it is only somewhere near that complexity when the stars align, like when you have very specific relationship between the size of array you need to sort and the range of integers that are in that array.

Comment: @wvxvw Which is exactly what this algorithm is. We're having exactly `n` buckets of size 1, and we skip all collisions or elements that don't fit in any bucket. If you don't believe me, I encourage you to give a counterexample for which this algorithm runs above `O(n)`.

Comment: @Sanchises on more thorough reading, I misunderstood the requirement. Now I see, this is correct.

Comment: @wvxvw: The number of exchanges is O (n). Each exchange is constant time, so the time is also O (n). Everything else in the algorithm is O (n). Total is O (n).

Comment: Just curious, how much time did it take for you to write the solution?

Comment: nums[i] != i + 1 and nums[i] != nums[nums[i] - 1] are the same

Comment: @KairatDoshekenov They are not, and this is easy to verify on [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/first-missing-positive/).

Answer (score 33):

How about this solution, which – if I'm not mistaken – should fulfill all requirements:

- create a second array
- run through all elements of the input array
- for each number set the respective key in the second array to true
- run through the second array and return the first key which value comes back as `undefined`
- if no match is found, return `1`, so it will work for an empty input array as well

---

```
function findNumber(values) {
  let result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
    if (0 <= values[i]) {
      result[values[i]] = true;
    }
  }

  for (let i = 1; i <= result.length; ++i) {
    if (undefined === result[i]) {
      return i;
    }
  }

  return 1
}
```

[Try it yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/uacqsa2h/)

---

<sup>Patrick and I had a discussion about the real time performance of our solutions (Here's [Patrick's elegant solution using `Set`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/179058/21444)). We set up a test, containing around 1000 elements in the input array, including lots of negative values. [You can try the test yourself](https://jsfiddle.net/02ux7ahn/).</sup>

<sup>[JollyJoker suggested a similar version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/179037/given-an-array-of-integers-return-the-smallest-positive-integer-not-in-it/179053#comment340062_179053) in the comments using JavaScript's built-ins `filter`, `reduce` and `findIndex`. I fixed the suggested solution for edge cases and added it to the performance test. You can now [test all three solutions](https://jsfiddle.net/tdqwtsf8/). Keep in mind that these built-ins come with some overhead.</sup>

<sup>[Janos added code for his algorithm as well](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/179042/21444) now. To complete the performance test, I've added it as well and [here's the final fiddle containing all four solutions](https://jsfiddle.net/7k7kwz92/).</sup>

Comment: This is an innovative solution. I have no idea if it is better or worse than my set based solution (i'm guessing slower, as it has less explicit looping). That said, take a +1

Comment: You shouldn't use an `Array` as an associative array. You really should use a `Set` instead.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, using set makes it O(N lg N).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Can you elaborate why you say: "*You shouldn't use an array as an associative array.*"? I'd say that the function uses a "*sparse*" array. This "*holey*" array acts like a normal array and the `length` is calculated correctly, even if you would set the key like `result['10']`. Whereas when using an "*associative*" value, like `result['ten']` the value is not calculated correctly. Here's a [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8c3vhc1/) for testing.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I also created some sort of [performance test](https://jsfiddle.net/ek68fhst/) for actual computing time. What do you think?

Comment: It's not just a sparse array because it has negative keys which all behave like properties on a plain object, and thus it is treated as an associative array. As for your performance test, [it was BS](https://jsfiddle.net/patrob10114/ek68fhst/1/), since you edited your algorithm to prevent your sparse array from being treated as an associative array with the `if (0 <= values[i])` condition not present in your answer. Without that, it performs even worse than my use of `Set()`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts True that: In my first version I forgot to handle negative values explicitly, and I didn't have time to update the answer accordingly this morning, only updated the test. I was updating my answer, while you were writing your comment. I also [changed the test](https://jsfiddle.net/02ux7ahn/) with your updated example containing lots of negative values.

Comment: That being said, I'm rather surprised at the performance difference even between declaring `result` as `[]` vs. `{}` (and changing the reference from `result.length` to `values.length` in the second `for` loop). I wouldn't have expected such a drastic change, as keys in arrays are still stored as strings. I'd be interested in seeing an explanation of this phenomenon based on an analysis of the v8 engine, but I'm personally not very familiar with the mechanics in v8 relating to this particular case.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think a sparse array has a lookup time of `O(1)`, making this probably `O(n log n)`.

Comment: @Sanchises Take a look at this question: [Big O of JavaScript arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11514308). Hope this answers your question.

Comment: @insertusernamehere The worst-case time complexity of a hashtable lookup and insert is `O(n)`, which makes your algorithm worst-case `O(n^2)`. Note that the question does not ask for average time complexity!

Comment: @Sanchises In the linked answer it says "*Insertion - Amortized O(1) if the value does not exist.*" and "*Access - O(1)*" - did I misinterpret something?

Comment: @insertusernamehere No. However, I still maintain that the worst-case lookup time for a hashtable is `O(n)` (if all the values hash to the same index, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)). Of course, in practice, especially for the range of numbers given, it will be very hard to construct such an example, and one would virtually never consider the worst-case time complexity of a hashtable (I think that's why it's not given in the linked question, either). I'm being pedantic, and don't worry, no downvotes given xD.

Comment: es6:`a => a.filter(x => x > 0 && x < a.length).reduce((acc, curr) => { acc[curr] = true; return acc; }, []).findIndex(y => !y);`

Comment: Nit-picking: Are yoda conditions idiomatic in JS? In any case, the second conditional can written this way: `if (undefined === result[i])` -> `if (!result[i])`

Comment: @JollyJoker Your solution looks like straight from PPCG - and I already thought about putting this problem there. :) That being said, your suggestion has two problems: It will always return `0`, as `y => !y` is satisfied for the first value anytime. And it will return `-1` for inputs containing negative values only or for an empty array. I've updated your solution: (`findIndex((value, index) => index > 0 && !value)` and `return result > 0 ? result : 1` and included it into the performance test and the question. Thank you.

Comment: @tokland I don't know whether it's idiomatic to be honest. I just like it but I'm good with both ways of writing conditions. At least [there is a rule on ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/yoda) for it - but it goes either way to require or to disallow it. Wordpress' JavaScript coding standards [suggests using Yoda conditions](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/javascript/#yoda-conditions) – but then again they do it, because it's in their PHP coding standards as well. And yes, of cource you're right that `!result[i]` would be equally good here.

Comment: @insertusernamehere Heh, I knew I should have tested

Comment: @insertusernamehere Initializing the reduce-accumulator to `[true]` instead of `[]` should make findIndex work better.

Comment: This gets top marks on Codility: https://imgur.com/a/wpkS87z. You can verify yourself here: https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/4-counting_elements/missing_integer/start/.

Answer (score 30):

In order to satisfy the *O(N)* time-complexity, construct a [`Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) in *O(N)* time and space complexity, then use a `while` loop which is considered <s>constant time relative to *N*</s> ***O(N)* as well** (thank you, [wchargin](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/179037/given-an-array-of-integers-return-the-smallest-positive-integer-not-in-it/179058?noredirect=1#comment339944_179058)), since the maximum possible number of iterations is equal to *N* and average performance of a `Set#has()` operation is *O(1)*. Because *O(N + N) = O(N)*, regarding time complexity, this solution is overall *O(N)* performance in both time and space:

```
function solution(A) {
  const set = new Set(A);
  let i = 1;

  while (set.has(i)) {
    i++;
  }

  return i;
}
```

---

<sup>While this is a relatively simplistic and deceivingly elegant implementation, [insertusernamehere's solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/179053/73672) is admittedly an order of magnitude faster, when using an array as a perfect hash table for non-negative integers instead.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this is also O(N) or O(N * log(N)), I will run a timed test between your answer and insertusernamehere. Fastest gets it.

Comment: a "in" test on a set is not O(1)

Comment: @JensSchauder Even if it was O(log N) (which it isn't), it doesn't matter. O(N + log N) = O(N).

Comment: @JensSchauder: Yes, it is: a `Set` in V8 or any other reasonable engine is implemented as a hash table with O(1) lookup. Patrick: it _would_ matter; if `set.has(i)` took O(log *N*) time, then you would have Ω(*N* log *N*) time worst-case, because you invoke `has` as many as *N* times.

Comment: @wchargin as I stated in my answer, the `while` loop is in constant time relative to `N` because the length of the array and the range of numbers to check are not related.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Sure they are. If the input array is the range of numbers from 1 to *N* inclusive, then the loop will run *N* times. *N* is an upper bound on the length of the loop, and moreover it is the best possible upper bound.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong and you are right, but using an array is still simpler than a Set, because for this case the identity is the perfect hash function, wouldn't it?

Comment: @JensSchauder: Yes, I agree: simply allocating an array of length `A.length` seems much more straightforward to me.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought while reading the question. it's almost pseudocode. :)

Comment: this is the only correct answer.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, how would we go about writing a test for the algorithm you offered?

Answer (score 8):

```
function solution(A) {
  for (i = 1; i < 1000000; i++) {
    if(!A.includes(i)) return i;
  }
}
```

Be consistent with your spacing.  You use a space after `for` but not for `if`.  The space helps separate language constructs from function calls.

For languages that use braces, always brace your one-liners (explicitly establishes the loop boundary) and prefer to have them on a separate line for readability, maintenance, and debugging (breakpoints!).

What happens if `len(A) >= 1,000,000`? Use the length of the array instead of an arbitrary value.  See below.

---

You can simplify this problem by filtering/partitioning any non-positive value from the array.  Once you have a filtered array of positive integers, you can use the filtered length to determine the upper-bound of the lowest positive integer.  For a distinct sequence of integers \$D = [1, 2, 3, ..., n]\$, the lowest positive integer is guaranteed to be \$n+1\$.  If you remove any value from \$D\$ and replace it with any **other** value (or simply remove it), then the lowest positive integer of \$D\$ is in the range \$[1, n]\$.  To find it, we can simply track integers in a boolean table, upto \$n\$, marking the ones witnessed.  A linear search of the boolean array for the first unmarked entry will give us a zero-based index of the lowest positive integer missing.  Add one to make it one-based once again.  Filtering, marking witnesses, and searching are all linear operations.

*Note* - Since you know the upper-bound, you can narrow your range further by making a second filter pass which removes any elements larger than the array length.  Would help with data locality if you have smallish arrays loaded with largish values.

While using a boolean array does meet your space complexity requirement, a constant space solution does exist.  Remember that every element in your filtered array is positive, so we can repurpose the sign bit of each value as a signal that we've witnessed a value of the sequence.  We can use the indices of the filtered array the same way we did the boolean array above.  Rather than search for the first element marked false (unwitnessed), we search for the first value that is still positive.

```
solution(A)
    Filter non-positive values from A
    Filter values larger than min(N-1, 999999) from A
    For each int in A that wasn't filtered out
        Let a zero-based index be the absolute value of the int - 1
    For each index upto min(N-1, 999999)
        if A[index] is positive, return the index + 1 (to one-based)
    otherwise return min(N, 100000)
```

So an array \$A = [ 1,  2,  3,  5,  6]\$, would have the following transformations:

```
abs(A[0]) = 1, to_0idx = 0, A[0] = 1, make_negative(A[0]), A = [-1,  2,  3,  5,  6]
abs(A[1]) = 2, to_0idx = 1, A[1] = 2, make_negative(A[1]), A = [-1, -2,  3,  5,  6]
abs(A[2]) = 3, to_0idx = 2, A[2] = 3, make_negative(A[2]), A = [-1, -2, -3,  5,  6]
abs(A[3]) = 5, to_0idx = 4, A[4] = 6, make_negative(A[4]), A = [-1, -2, -3,  5, -6]
```

A linear search for the first positive value returns an index of 3.  Converting back to a one-based index results in \$solution(A) = 3 + 1 = 4\$

Comment: In the case that the integers in the array are not distinct I think the statement "Filter non-positive values from A" needs to be complemented with "Filter non-positive & duplicate values from A". I am not sure if .distinct() is linear complexity though.

Comment: Addendum: If the integers are not distinct then *maybe* (and I could be wrong here) a better way to tackle the resulting issue would be to modify "Make the value in filtered[index] negative" to read "If filtered[index] is not already negative then make the value in filtered[index] negative". Again I am not entirely sure about this.

Comment: I'm getting TIMEOUT ERROR for large_1(1.66 sec), large_2( >6.00 sec, 4.97 sec) and large_3(1.080 s) performance tests. On my macbook pro I'm getting 10ms for 1000000 random positive array

Comment: this has o(n2) complexity :(

Comment: @AlexeySh. Adjusted the code so it filters out values larger than your array size (or first 100k). This is the reason for the timeout error.

Comment: @AshokRaj Filtering is an unstable linear complexity algorithm that moves the wanted values from the back of an array to the locations of unwanted elements we forward scan through. Scanning, either to negate values or find the min/max, is also a linear complexity operation.

Answer (score 4):

One thing to note is how much space you are allowed to use. You can use up to `O(n)` space, (enough to make a full copy of your data). Your code currently is slow because it uses `O(n)` `in` statements, each of which are `O(n)`. This means that if only there existed a data structure on which `in` statements were `O(1)`, you would have solved your problem. Thankfully `Set` has exactly this property. Therefore, the only change you need to make to your solution is turn your `list` into a `set`.

Comment: Thanks, can you expand on this. Would the array `A` be consider a set here?

Comment: My answer is basically the same as Patricks. The key is to make a `Set` so you get fast membership testing.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript you can do this:

1. First, remove duplicates if any

```js
    var A=[4,3,2,1,0,1,-3];
    const remove_duplicates = A.filter((number, index) => {
          return A.indexOf(number) === index
    })
```

2. Secondly, order your array using the JavaScript `Array.sort()` method, with complexity \$O(n\log(n))\$ ([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234683/javascript-array-sort-implementation)):

   ```
    const sorted = remove_duplicates.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
    //returns the array ordered [-3,0,1,2,3,4]
   ```
3. Only iterate over the ordered array. For every value, check if the value is bigger than 0 and if the next element on the array is not equal to the current value + 1.

```js
    // find smallest positive integer not in sorted greater than 0
    // return only valid number, unless all negative values else return 1
    const result = sorted.map((number, index) => {
        if (number > 0 && sorted[index + 1] !== sorted[index] + 1) {
            return sorted[index] + 1
        }
    }).filter(number => number !== undefined)[0]

    return result === undefined ? 1 : result
```

Comment: Except that O(n log n) > O(n), which is the required time complexity. This does not satisfy the requirements for the requested code.

Answer (score 2):

You can trivially find a faster solution than the one you've already given, by simply sorting the array first, stripping all non-positive integers and start the search from there -- this makes the algorithm an \$O(n \log n)\$ algorithm in the worst case and in the best case an \$O(n)\$ algorithm and doesn't require any extra space.

Alternatively, just add all the positive numbers to a set and find the smallest positive number that's not in that set. If you want to do this in less than \$O(n \log n)\$ time, you need to use a bitvector; go through all the elements and set bit `n` in the vector to `true`, when the element you're inspecting is equal to `n`. This will take \$O(n)\$ time and \$O(n)\$ space.

To get the size of the bit vector simply find the largest integer (and the smallest while you're at it) and allocate that many bits. This can also be done in \$O(n)\$ time. If the smallest integer isn't 1, then the number you're looking for *is* 1.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `set` makes the problem O(N lg N) as associated directories are lg N for each insert, delete and find. Unless you use the hash version of the associated directories, in which case you can't find next in O(1) as worst case is O(N).

Sorting with a comparison function always result in O(N lg N), but other specialized sorts doesn't, like counting sort.

So we could try with a specialization of counting sort, lets call it existence sort as we are not interested in how many but only in if it exists.

Further we prune the range of numbers in the original array to only those between 1 and 100000 included.

Pseudo code for a this method:

```
min = 1
max = 100000

bool num[100000] = false // 100000 long array of bool, add 1 (one) if your language array index start at 0 (zero)


for (i = 1; i < 1000000; i++) {
  can = A[i];
  if(can >= min && can <= max) {
    num[can] = true;    // register numbers that exist in our range
  }
}

for (i = min; i <= max; i++)
  if (!num[i])
    return i;
```

Comment: Sorting with a comparison based method is only $O(n \log n)$ in the worst case. It's trivial to make it $O(n)$ in the best case (even for multiple such cases at the same time), and gradually move from $O(n)$ to $O(n \log n)$ as the list is "less" sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a PHP solution (initial test):

```
<?php
$a = array(
    2, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7,
);

function solution(array $a = array()){
    /**
     * Assumes that the first positive integer
     * in an empty array will be 1 - also stops
     * potential for infinite loop in while()
     * below
     */
    if(!count($a)){
        return 1;
    }

    $i = 0;

    while(in_array(++$i, $a)){}

    return $i;
}

echo solution($a);
```

and here is a refactored version based on feedback in the comments below:

```
function solution(array $a = array()){
    /**
     * Assumes that the first positive integer
     * in an empty array will be 1 - also stops
     * potential for infinite loop in while()
     * below
     */
    if(!count($a)){
        return 1;
    }

    /**
     * Lowest possible number in set
     * -1 so it starts counting at
     * -1000000
     */
    $i =-1000001;
    $c = 1;

    while($c){
        $i++;
        if(($i > 0 && !in_array($i, $a)) || $i > 1000000){
            $c = 0;
        }
    }

    /**
     * If $i is negative, the lowest positive
     * integer in set will be 1, otherwise it
     * will be the set value of $i unless $i
     * is out of range for this task
     */
    if($i <= 1000000){
        return ($i < 1) ? 1 : $i;
    }
    return 'Value out of range';
}
```

Comment: I'd say that this is the same as the OP's code: This means it is `O(n^2)` instead of `O(n)` and does not fulfill the requirement of the question.

Comment: @lampshade I have made amendments to the function above - now checks for a range of -1000000 to +1000000 inclusive.

Comment: You don't need to test all negative values actually. What I meant is: You have a while loop which runs in `O(n)` which uses `in_array` which is also `O(n)` so your time complexity is `O(n^2)`. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution in Java should be within the boundaries of time and space complexity:

```
public int solution(int[] A)
{
    java.util.HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(A.length); //O(n) space
    for (int i : A) // O(N)
    {
        if (!map.containsKey(i))
        {
            map.put(i, i);
        }
    }
    int smallestPositive = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000001; i++) // ~O(N)
    {
        if (map.containsKey(i) && map.get(i) <= smallestPositive)
        {
            smallestPositive = map.get(i) + 1;
        }
    }
    return smallestPositive;
}
```

I was about to write that you might even ditch the `HashMap` and loop over `A` in the second loop as 1,000,000 is a constant and should be negligible, but it looks like they specifically made a point in the question that \$N\$ is 100,000 which is smaller so you can consider the second loop to be of \$O(n)\$ time.

It sums up to \$O(n) + O(n) = O(n)\$ time and \$O(n)\$ space for the map.